# What the output should be there?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

The output should be

```
strString = değiştim
wkString  = NULL
```

but it is not. WHY?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface learnARC : NSObject {
    NSString *strString, __weak *wkString;
}

@property (strong) NSString *strString;
@property (weak) NSString *wkString;

-(void) yaz;

@end

#import "learnARC.h"

@implementation learnARC

@synthesize wkString, strString;

-(void) yaz {
    NSString *anaString = @"anaString";
    strString = anaString;
    wkString = anaString;
    NSLog(@"\nstrString = %@\nwkString  = %@",strString,wkString);

    anaString = @"değiştim";
    NSLog(@"\nstrString = %@\nwkString  = %@",strString,wkString);
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        learnARC *lrnarc = [[learnARC alloc]init];
        [lrnarc yaz];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is output then  ?

Comment: Both NSLog statements should genereate the output `"strString = anaString \n nwkString = anastring"`

Answer (score 2):

> WHY?

<s>Because you're captalizing your question instead of your class names...</s>

Seriously, the weak reference should **not** be `NULL`. You have assigned a pointer to it (a pointer to the string `@"anaString"`). And since string literals have static storage duration, they are never deallocated during the lifetime of the program. (I think you may be confusing variables with properties?)

Comment: so what is difference between strong and weak for NSString?

Comment: @agulerer Not "for NSString". For every object. The one increases the reference count of the object assigned, the other doesn't.

Comment: (Which is wholly futile seeing as immutable constant NSStrings have a retain count of close to `NSUIntegerMax`)